# Was there any avatar of Nara during Ramavatar?

Tags: mahabharata, vishnu, ramayana, avatars

It is being said that Nara and Narayan together takes birth in each Yug to establish the Dharma.
During Krishna avatar, Krishna is the avatar of Narayan while Arjun is the avatar of Nara.

I want to know if Nara took avatar during Ramavatar. Ram was Narayan.
Who was Nara ?

Comment: Rama is not Sage Narayana's incarnation, he was Lord Vishnu's incarnation only.